# python equivalent of curl -X POST -F "name=blahblah" -F "file=@blahblah.jpg"

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Can someone please help me with the python equivalent of the curl command:

python equivalent of `curl -X POST -F "name=blahblah" -F "file=@blahblah.jpg"`

I would like to you python requests module, but I am not clear on the options to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`requests.post` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) with `files` keyword arguments to post a multipart-encoded file:

```
import requests

url = 'http://...'
with open('blahblah.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post(url, files={'blahblah': f})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to remind you not to specify headers to `{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` as the real header will look like `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=${bound}'`, this is different from curl example:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.biz.weibo.com/file/sliceupload' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer $ADS_API_ACCESS' \
-H 'Accept: application/json,application/text+gw2.0' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F 'upload_id=00ebd5f30dfe7950a145daeae5395b82' \
-F 'name=ceshi.txt' \
-F 'file_length=5242881' \
-F 'check=92af8ade8b5db20e183ec970549ca4e7' \
-F 'slice_check=a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c' \
-F 'part_number=2' \
-F 'length=1' \
-F 'file=@/all.1.txt'
```

and correlated python code for this curl command is:

```
params = {
    'upload_id': upload_id,
    'name': file_name,
    'check': file_md5,
    'slice_check': md5,
    'part_number': chunk_index + 1,
    'file_length': file_size,
    'length': part_size if part_size < file_size else file_size,
}
resp = requests.post('https://api.biz.weibo.com/file/sliceupload', data=params, files={'file': open(chunk_path, 'rb'),}, headers=self.default_headers)
```

In addition, I've found an online tool which is able to convert curl command to code form in other languages(Python, Go and etc.): https://curl.trillworks.com/